# What happened to [username removed]?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users

[username removed] stopped posting here quite suddenly. I remember him to be very critical of the MWI, so I'm going to poke in his eye here by saying that the Universe is in a superposition of all possibilities consistent with the record about his postings, so anything that could have happened to explain why the postings stopped has actually happened. If someone knows what happened and communicates this to me then from my point of view, the universe will effectively split into the different possible answers that I'll get (I'll cease to be identical in the different sectors).

Comment: Since the user in question is completely anonymous on here and seems unlikely to appear to answer this question themselves, I'm going to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

That user appears to have decided to stop visiting the site.  There's some non-public information which confirms that their decision was voluntary.  They had expressed an intention to return, but you know how life is.  Perhaps they'll come back eventually.